# Symbol и Symbol.for - в чем разница?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять что дает объявления `Symbol` идентификаторов через `for`.
Читал несколько статей, суть разницы не уловил.
В чем разница и в каких случаях полезно через `sybmol.for` объявить свойство объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оф. документах вроде как все описано

> В противоположность вызову Symbol(), функция Symbol.for() создаёт символ, доступный в глобальном списке реестра символов. Symbol.for() не создаёт новый символ при каждом вызове, вместо этого, метод сначала проверяет, существует ли символ с заданным идентификатором в реестре — и возвращает его, если тот присутствует. Если символ с заданным ключом не найден, Symbol.for() создаст новый глобальный символ.

То есть по сути, символ сравнивается как и объект, по ссылке. Даже если мы создадим два "одинаковых" символа, они не будут равны

```
const aSymbol = Symbol('a');
const bSymbol = Symbol('a'); // должны быть равны?

aSymbol === bSymbol; // нет :(
```

Если создавать символ через `Symbol.for`, то мы сможем получить этот символ в другом месте.

```
function createSymbol(name) {
   Symbol.for(name);
}

createSymbol('a');
const aSymbol = Symbol.for('a');
const bSymbol = Symbol.for('a');

aSymbol === bSymbol; // теперь норм
```

Если говорить простым языком, то `Symbol.for` - это просто хранилище для символов, к которому можно обратиться по имени. Сами можете такое сделать с помощью обычного объекта

```
window.GlobalSymbol = {
  store_: {},
  for: function(name) {
    if(!this.store_[name]) {
      this.store_[name] = Symbol(name)
    }
    return this.store_[name]
  }
}

console.log(GlobalSymbol.for('name') === GlobalSymbol.for('name'));
console.log(GlobalSymbol.for('name'));
```